# android dimens value for different resolution devices

Tags: android, resolution

I want setup different dimen-values for different resolution(dp) devices, how ?

just in my dimens.xml

```
 <resources>

    <!-- for 1280x720 dp ,Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->

    <dimen name="image_thumbnail_size">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_thumbnail_spacing">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_detail_pager_margin">160dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">80dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">100dp</dimen>

    <!--  for 640x360 dp -->
<!-- 
        <dimen name="image_thumbnail_size">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_thumbnail_spacing">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_detail_pager_margin">80dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">30dp</dimen>
     -->
```

add:
I have two devices, the resolution is 1280x720 ,but my phone dp is 640x360 , and another is 1280x720

Answer (score 4):

Create seperate values folders, each with a different suffex. Some examples:

```
values-normal (for phone versions)
values-large (for 7" tablets)
values-xlarge (for large tablets)
```

Place a dimensions.xml file in each of these folders, in each one, specify different values for each variable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to get this to you late but you can use the same folder combinations that you use for drawables with the values folder.  Here is an example

```
values-ldpi/dimens.xml
values-hdpi/dimens.xml
values-xhdpi/dimens.xml
```